# Can anyone explain this?

Tags: scripture, vedas, philosophy, nyaya-sutra, schools

क्रूराः कृतोऽञ्जलिरयं बलिरेष दत्तः कायो मया प्रहरतात्र यथाभिलाषम् अभ्यर्थये वितथवाङ्गयपांशुवर्षेर्मा माऽऽविलीकुरुतकीर्ति नदीः परेषाम् ।। 7

O HEARTLESS BARBARIANS! I HAVE ALMOST KILLED MYSELF WHILE TRYING TO REFUTE YOUR DOCTRINES, BY SUBJECTING MY BODY TO ALL KINDS OF TRIALS AND TRIBULATIONS. PLEASE TAKE PITY ON ME AND DO NOT TRY TO TAR THE REPUTATION OF YOUR OPPONENTS.

Source- Nyaya vartika tatparya tika a sub-commentary on nyaya sutras

VĀCASPATI MISHRA, THE BRILLIANT PHILOSOPHER OF THE 10TH CENTURY, AFTER COMPLETING HIS TREATISE AND ASKING BUDDHISTS NOT TO REFUTE THEM ANYMORE.

Well, Vascapti Misra was a follower of Advaita Vedanta but he also wrote works on other schools as well. Like the above-mentioned text which is a work on the Nyaya school of Hinduism.

Can anyone explain the context behind this statement of Vascapti Misra?

Generally, through such texts, every other school of philosophy is refuted. Has Vascapti Misra only refuted Buddhists?

[image: Buddhist making fun of the statement]

[image]

Comment: Making a mountain out of a molehill. While there may be some backstory, it's pretty common in Sanskrit dialectic and literature to end in caraṇa filled with utter humility - Some like to boast their work in the end by stating it greater than the words of Sarasvatī herself, the others end their work with all humility solely dedicating to Bhagavat and for example comparing their works to rare dissonant sounds from veena which ask for ignorance from wise ones, when it's obvious that the work is masterpiece. On the point of refutation, the work utilizes many different opinions as Pūrvapakṣa.

Comment: Probably got stressed over refuting them it's natural the work is hard after all.

Comment: The translation is not really good, its wording isn't really proper and not conveying Vācaspati's actual intention (tainted by the translator's interpretation), as in the surrounding verses. The quoted verse appears at the end of Vācaspati's comm., as an afterword, after he has completely commented on the Nyāyasūtra. It's a part of a kinda poem by him, when this sentence is seen in that poem, it is actually much better than this translation. https://archive.org/details/nyayavartikatatparyatikaofvachaspatimisraanantlalthakuricpr_202003_952_M/page/n713/mode/2up?view=theater